# Qual è il significato di "sfiancare" in questo contesto?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Disse che aveva sbagliato a seguire Enzo a San Giovanni a Teduccio, voleva tornare al rione. 
>         «Al rione?». 
>         «Sì». 
>         «Sei pazza». 
>         «Appena mi sento meglio lo faccio». 
>         La rimproverai, le dissi che era un pensiero indotto dalla febbre, che il rione l’**avrebbe sfiancata**, che rimetterci piede era una stupidaggine.

Ho cercato il significato di "sfiancare" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia, non capisco molto bene qual è il senso di questo verbo nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: stancare? cosa trovi nei dizionari che non ti convince?

Comment: @mario: Quello che appare nei dizionari è deformare, logorare...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Sfiancare](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/sfiancare.php)*** è usato nel brano in senso figurato col significato di:

> - fig. Spossare: *il viaggio mi ha sfiancato.*   Logorare, indebolire gravemente: *l'asma gli ha sfiancato polmoni e cuore.*

(Hoepli)

L'autore vuol dire che ritornare  nel rione l'avrebbe stancata, logorata fisicamente e forse anche mentalmente (dipende dal contesto) per cui suggerisce di non farlo.